# Error installing Pillow on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, pip, ubuntu-14.04, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to install Pillow on Ubuntu 14.04 using this command:

```
pip install Pillow
```

but the installation fails with this error:

```
ValueError: --enable-jpeg requested but jpeg not found, aborting.
```

Answer (score 89, accepted):

The problem was that the package `libjpeg-dev` was not installed. To solve the problem you should do this:

```
sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev
```

Comment: This. Throw in `zlib1g-dev` as well if you want PNG support.

Comment: This worked for me too! They should have `libjpeg-dev` as a dependency then!

Comment: After this `sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev`

Comment: yum install libjpeg-devel on Fedora

Comment: @JahongirRahmonov See my answer below.  The dependencies are declared, but sometimes pip relies on an outdated cache.

Answer (score 20):

Make sure Python-development packages are installed, if not then install it using the following commands :

**For Ubuntu**

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev python3-setuptools
```

**For Fedora**

```
sudo dnf install python-devel
```

After installing the development packages install the following :

**For Ubuntu**

```
sudo apt-get install libtiff5-dev libjpeg8-dev zlib1g-dev \
libfreetype6-dev liblcms2-dev libwebp-dev tcl8.6-dev tk8.6-dev python-tk
```

**For Fedora**

```
sudo dnf install libtiff-devel libjpeg-devel libzip-devel freetype-devel \
lcms2-devel libwebp-devel tcl-devel tk-devel
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to install the missing dependencies and libraries that Pillow requires for it to work. Find the dependencies [here](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.0.0/installation.html#linux-installation)

This are the current dependancies/libraries for Ubuntu 14.04 for Pilllow 3.0.0+. Install them by running the command below

```
sudo apt-get install libtiff5-dev libjpeg8-dev zlib1g-dev \
libfreetype6-dev liblcms2-dev libwebp-dev tcl8.6-dev tk8.6-dev python-tk
```

Answer (score 1):

There may be a problem where pip is relying on a cached version of the dependencies, and clearing the cache can sometimes solve the problem.  Just type

```
$ rm -rf ~/.cache/pip
```

Source: [github issue](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/1275)

Answer (score -2):

You need to follow this tutorial [Install pillow doc](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.0.x/installation.html).

If you had installed, just uninstall and reinstall again:

```
$ pip uninstall pillow
$ pip install pillow --no-cache-dir
```