# Install error for PIL/PILLOW in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I have tried to install both the PIL and PILLOW packages in pycharm but I'm getting some errors when I try from the terminal as suggested. How can I resolve them?

Error:

```
ValueError: jpeg is required unless explicitly disabled using --disable-jpeg, aborting
```

followed by:

```
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-v9j6b44w/Pillow/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-im6_90gt-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-v9j6b44w/Pillow
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install python development tools first

Python 2:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev python-setuptools
```

Python 3:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev python3-setuptools
```

See other requirements in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34965341/3125566)